# Does using the load step to load a pipeline block still count as a declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have two Jenkins jobs that use two Jenkinsfiles that are "almost" exactly the same, so I wanted to abstract the Jenkinsfile into a common one.

```
// commonPipeline.groovy

def buildImage(imageName) {
  pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
      stage('Build Image') {
        steps {
          script {
            sh "${imageName}/build_image.sh"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

return this
```

```
// Jenkinsfile_foo
commonPipeline = load 'commonPipeline.groovy'
commonPipeline.buildImage('foo')
```

Does `Jenkinsfile_foo` represent a valid Jenkins declarative pipeline?

If not, what is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: This is scripted syntax, but why does it need to be declarative?

Comment: I keep reading everywhere that declarative is the recommended way as it makes builds more modular, predictable, debuggable, and alike

Comment: You should be cautious of opinions that declare absolute best practices as reality is almost always much more nuanced and intricate. If scripted syntax fits your current and future environment better then why not use it?

Comment: Sounds wise. Although I do have docker-image-based declarative agents that should run my build. Does this change anything?

Comment: The syntax is more awkward because the `node` directive cannot use `docker` wiithin the directive, but the plugin still enables equivalent functionality. Also: if you converted your pipeline method loaded above into a global variable method within a library that is invoked from a pipeline, then you could easily convert to declarative (agnostic of the remainder of your current codebase).